# htaccess not working for simple RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Should be simple

somedomain.com/cutsmart - new url should be -  somedomain.com/lp_cutsmart.php

Tested with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/cutsmart$ /lp_cutsmart.php [R=301,L]

But getting 404 when lp_cutsmart.php exist

Answer (score 0):

If the "cutsmart" part of your visitor's URL can change to anything which contains only a-z letters, and you want the visitor's browser to be redirected to a resource on your server with a path which contains that a-z term (such as /lp_cutsmart.php) then try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /lp_$1.php
```

Note that in a .htaccess file you don't need a slash at the start of the regex pattern, because a .htaccess file always assumes it is working out of the directory in which the .htaccess file is located.

If you simply want a request for /cutsmart to always redirect to /lp_cutsmart.php then you're probably better of using a simple Redirect:

```
Redirect permanent /cutsmart http://somedomain.com/lp_cutsmart.php
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I was very busy moving. And thank you, thank you very much. I went with RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /lp_$1.php so not to catch directories. This ,somedomain.com/cutsmart, alias works and this ,somedomain.com/cutsmart/ , would be somedomain.com/cutsmart/index.php . Do you forsee any issues?

Comment: I would want to avoid any chance that an actual directory could have the same name as a rewrite alias, but if this is absolutely necessary then make sure to think carefully to avoid any confusion or unexpected behaviour.